# Why do razor compile errors not show up in VS2012 when one does a build, and can it be resolved?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, visual-studio-2012

I notice that VS2012 fails to raise errors in Razor Views when one build the web project. If you go into the View, one sees the error highlighted. I use resharper, so it may be VS or Resharper doing this?

Just seems strage that VS does not show these errors at build time.

Any way to resolve?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Razor views are not compiled with the application unless you set `MvcBuildViews` to `true` in the .csproj file.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" 
         DefaultTargets="Build" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
  <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

Comment: No opinion.  Depends on your development process, your tool chain, etc.  If you have a lot of views this can increase your compile times.